# Can I specify the join conditions of a relationship when writing a query instead of doing so in my model class?

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have three models...

```
class Customer(db.Model, TimestampMixin):
    pk = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)

class User(db.Model, TimestampMixin):
    pk = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)

class CustomerUserStat(db.Model):
    __table_args__ = (
        UniqueConstraint("customer_pk", "user_pk", name="customer_pk_user_pk"),
    )
    pk = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    customer_pk = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("customers.pk"), nullable=False)
    user_pk = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("users.pk"), nullable=False)
    data = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, default=0)
```

I’ve tried...

```
m.Customer.query.outerjoin(
  m.CustomerUserStat,
  (m.CustomerUserStat.user_pk == entity.pk)
  & (m.CustomerUserStat.customer_pk == m.Customer.pk)
).add_entity(m.CustomerUserStat)
```

But that gives me a tuple with a Customer object and a CustomerUserStat (or None if one doesn’t exist), close but not quite what I am looking for.

I’ve also tried adding a userstats relationship to the Customer model and ...

```
m.Customer.query.outerjoin(m.Customer.userstats
).filter(m.CustomerUserStat.user_pk == user.pk
).options(contains_eager(m.Customer.userstats))
```

But that didn’t produce any results if the user's CustomerUserStat record was missing.

Ultimately, I would like to write a query that will give me a list of Customer objects with an attribute that has an instance of CustomerUserStat for a user that I specify in the query and I need to be able to order by the CustomerUserStat.data field and paginate the results.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are looking for the [AssociationProxy pattern](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html)

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this hack to get the query that I needed. In my Flask view function, I defined a new class that inherits from the original and added the relationship to it. Then I use the new class to create the query.

```
class TempCustomer(m.Customer):
  userstats = db.relationship(
    m.CustomerUserStat,
      primaryjoin=(m.Customer.pk == m.CustomerUserStat.customer_pk) & 
                  (m.CustomerUserStat.user_pk == agent.pk),
      uselist=False,
      viewonly=True,
      lazy="joined",
    )
    
q = TempCustomer.query.outerjoin(m.CustomerUserStat, (m.Customer.pk == 
    m.CustomerUserStat.customer_pk) & (m.CustomerUserStat.user_pk == agent.pk),)
```

This works for me, but doesn't seem like the best solution.

It also results in two LEFT JOINS for the same data which is probably not the most efficient.